# Create Audio element dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, appendchild

I need to create an audio tag dynamically in between `<div class="audio-player" id="song"></div>`

**Need to create:**

`<audio id="audio-player"  controls="controls" src="media/Blue Browne.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">`

**in:**
`<div class="audio-player" id="song"></div>`
please help its very important for me

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 30):

You can do it in multiple ways. Here are some:

**Using `innerHTML`**

*Use this if you want to replace all of the inner HTML, and do not care about references to elements.*

```
document.getElementById('song').innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" controls="controls" src="media/Blue Browne.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">';
```

**Using `appendChild`**

*Use this if you want to have a reference to your audio element, and maybe other elements that are already in there.*

```
var sound      = document.createElement('audio');
sound.id       = 'audio-player';
sound.controls = 'controls';
sound.src      = 'media/Blue Browne.mp3';
sound.type     = 'audio/mpeg';
document.getElementById('song').appendChild(sound);
```

**Using `insertAdjacentHTML`**

*Use this method if you have other elements in there that you previously referenced and want to keep a reference to, but don't care about a reference to the `audio` element for now.*

```
document.getElementById('song').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<audio id="audio-player" controls="controls" src="media/Blue Browne.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">');
```