# Creating "type" parameter for HTML5 <audio> programmatically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm currently creating an audio element with JS like this :

```
var newAE = document.createElement('audio');
    newAE.id = "ios-audio";
    newAE.src = obj.media;
document.getElementById('ios').appendChild(newAE);
```

Which is great, but I need to also programmatically set the `type` based on the content of the incoming `obj.media` value.

```
type="audio/mpeg"
type="audio/ogg"
```

I thought this would work :

```
var enctype = 'audio/mpeg';

if (obj.media == "https://example.com/myaudiofile.ogg") {
  enctype = 'audio/ogg';
}

var newAE = document.createElement('audio');
  newAE.id = "ios-audio";
  newAE.src = obj.media;
  newAE.type = enctype;
document.getElementById('ios').appendChild(newAE);
```

But it doesn't create the `type` parameter at all. I still end up with this in the DOM :

```
<audio id="ios-audio" src="https://example.com/myaudiofile.mp3"></audio>
```

When the desired result in this case would be :

```
<audio id="ios-audio" src="https://example.com/myaudiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

I guess I'm doing it wrong so could somebody point me in the right direction please?

Example below (without the mp3/ogg switch as it's irrelevant)

```js
function create(media) {

  var enctype = "audio/mpeg";
  
  var newAE = document.createElement('audio');
      newAE.id = "ios-audio";
      newAE.src = media;
      newAE.type = enctype;
  document.getElementById('ios').appendChild(newAE);

  var player = document.getElementById('ios-audio');
  setTimeout(function() {
    player.play();
    console.log("playing");
    console.log(player);
  }, 50);
}

create('https://ia800508.us.archive.org/15/items/LoveThemeFromTheGodfather/02LoveThemeFromTheGodfather.mp3');
```

```html
<div id="ios"></div>
```

Comment: Does the audio fail to play? Because if it's just about it's appearance in the DOM it shouldn't matter as long as the property of the underlying element is okay. Otherwise, use `innerHTML` to set exactly the HTML you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735208/215552

Comment: It plays mp3 files just fine but when it gets an OGG file it plays for about 30 seconds and then stops on iOS Safari. I assumed the issue with Safari was the missing type?

Comment: @RobG dev tools in the browser

Comment: Use `newAE.setAttribute('type', enctype)`, but that may not fix the playback issue.

Comment: @RobG Just added a working snippet, came back and saw your last comment. Doh! How did I miss that. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks man ;)

Comment: Just realised that the whole time I was talking about OGG above I actually meant AAC - which uses the 'audio/mpeg' type anyway. OGG isn't even supported on iOS Safari, so it turns out this whole effort was pointless in that respect. But, adding the type correctly has improved playback load times so every cloud.. :)

Comment: @spice RobG mentioned the 'type' on the `<audio>` tag may not fix your issue. He is correct, it's useless on an `<audio>` tag, it belongs to the `<source>` tag. If you use a `<source>` tag and add `type` to it, your value should be [`type="audio/aac"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types#wikiArticle) See my answer.

Comment: @zer00ne—yep. The fact that adding an attribute as a property doesn't "work" is a hint that it's not a standard attribute. I just didn't have time to check it out for the [*audio* element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)… ;-)

Comment: But even for source, you don't really need it, just let the server tells what it will send is enough.

Comment: @RobG that's a good point concerning property vs.standard attribute.

Comment: @Kaiido agreed, yet it's a habit I picked up a while back like `<meta charset='utf-8'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `<source>` and `[type]`

I believe the **[`[type]` attribute belongs to the `<source>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-type)**. An `<audio>` tag can only have one `[src]` attribute and when more than one is needed, `<source>` tags are added for each `[src]`. The `[type]` attribute is needed to designate the MIME for multiple `[src]`.

---

### Demo

**if demo does not function on SO, review this functioning demo on [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/MraoXsO1svTdcztNXoTk/)**

```js
var aTag = document.createElement('audio');
aTag.id = 'a0';
aTag.controls = true;

var sMP3 = document.createElement('source');
sMP3.src = 'https://instaud.io/_/2JCu.mp3';
sMP3.type = 'audio/mpeg';

var sOGG = document.createElement('source');
sOGG.src = 'https://instaud.io/_/2Mxg.ogg';
sOGG.type = 'audio/ogg';

aTag.appendChild(sMP3);
aTag.appendChild(sOGG);

document.querySelector('.dock').appendChild(aTag);
```

```html
<fieldset class='dock'>
  <legend>Audio and Source Tags</legend>
</fieldset>
```

---

Comment: What do you mean by *demo doesn't work on SO*? How is the plnkr related to this Q/A?