# Using Javascript to Change HTML sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would like to change the audio element I inserted with another audio element.

I checked the solution at: [Create Audio element dynamically in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735208/create-audio-element-dynamically-in-javascript), and I don't understand why my code isn't working.

In HTML I have:

```
<audio id="sound" src="shush1.mp3" controls>
    Your Browser Does Not Support the Audio Feature
</audio>
```

and in `babySounds.js` I have:

```
var sound = document.createElement('audio');
sound.src = "Shush2.mp3";
sound.controls = "controls";
document.getElementById("sound").appendChild(sound);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `<audio>`, but I would assume it's not working because you are nesting the tags with your `appendChild()`, such that you have `<audio id="sound" src="shush1.mp3" controls\> Your Browser Does Not Support the Audio Feature <audio src="Shush2.mp3" controls="controls"></audio></audio\>`. You probably want to replace the original instead.

Comment: You're appending a new audio element to the existing one. Did you mean to [_replace_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) the existing one with the new one instead?

Comment: Try using [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) like this `document.getElementById("sound").replaceWith(sound)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code attempts to append your new `audio` element as a *child* of the one that's already there (`appendChild`), rather than replacing it.

If you want to replace it, you can use the [`replaceWith` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) instead in all non-obsolete browsers:

```
const sound = /*...*/;
document.getElementById("sound").replaceWith(sound);`
```

But if you just want to change what the sound is, you can assign to the existing element's `src` property instead, there's no need to create a whole new element:

```
document.getElementById("sound").src = "Shush2.mp3";
```

From [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#location-of-the-media-resource):

> If a `src` attribute of a media element is set or changed, the user agent must invoke the media element's media element load algorithm.
>
> ...
>
> The `src` IDL attribute on media elements must [reflect](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflect) the content attribute of the same name.